# Log4j2 custom level settings

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm trying to configure custom level in log4j2 properties file but it's not working. I've tried many different ways how to configure it, but none of them is working. Here are few lines from the code:

```
customLevel.cl1.name = MY2
customLevel.cl1.intLevel = 10

appender.r4.type = RollingFile
appender.r4.name = userLog
appender.r4.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.r4.filter.threshold.level = MY2
appender.r4.fileName = ${sys:user.home}/Vyv2.user
appender.r4.filePattern = ${sys:user.home}/Vyv2.user.%i
appender.r4.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.r4.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] [%t] %c - %msg%n
appender.r4.policies.type = Policies
appender.r4.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.r4.policies.size.size=100KB
appender.r4.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.r4.strategy.max = 10

rootLogger.level = ALL
rootLogger.appenderRef.l4.ref = userLog
rootLogger.appenderRef.l4.level = MY2
```

This part is not working:

```
customLevel.cl1.name = MY2
customLevel.cl1.intLevel = 10
```

Why? Thank you

Comment: I have bypassed the problem by changing .properties file to .xml and everyting is working.. But I still don't how to do it with .properties file.

Comment: I'm wondering if this might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), why do you want to use custom levels?

Comment: We use log4j for debug, info and error logging. Now we need to log more information not related to app's health and we didn't wanted to use another logging system. That's why I need to set custom levels for storing more files.

Comment: You might consider using [markers](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/markers.html) together with the [MarkerFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#MarkerFilter). Markers are supported by other logging frameworks and if you ever decided to switch it should be easier to do so than trying to port a custom log level.